# Importing existing repository code in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, import

I found on code.google.com an interesting code i want to translate my language.

This is the software source:

https://code.google.com/p/ankfood/downloads/detail?name=AnKFood1.6%20source.zip

After i download it, i ope eclipse, New-->Android project from existing code
and then try to run it, but it gives me many resource errors.

Could anyone try to run it and tell me if it's a problem of my eclipse version?

Many thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. I just use File > Import. I gotta fix some unprotected apostrophes in `eng_strings.xml` but otherwise it works fine.

ADT version 22.0.5

Eclipse 3.8.2